# React - can't update state correctly inside single useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display some data into the `table` element using react.
The table will have `5 columns and 9 rows`.

I am using a state which holds the data to be displayed in the table as array of arrays,

```js
const [displayedSlot, setDisplayedSlot] = useState(
  hours.map(() => days.map(() => ""))
);
```

where,

```js
const days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"];
const hours = [
  "8:40-9:40",
  "9:40-10:40",
  "10:40-11:40",
  "11:40-12:40",
  "12:40-13:40",
  "13:40-14:40",
  "14:40-15:40",
  "15:40-16:40",
  "17:40-18:40",
];
```

I also have two additional states as well,

```js
const [possibleSchedules, setPossibleSchedules] = useState([]); 
const [currentSchedule, setCurrentSchedule] = useState(null);
```

`possibleSchedules` holds the data can be displayed in the table(it's filled after some user input), and, `currentSchedule` holds the index for which possible schedule will be displayed.

When the user changes the value of the `currentSchedule`, I want to clear the table and display new schedule data in the table.

What I have tried initially as follows,

```js
     useEffect(() => {
        // I was hoping this would clear table before I update it with new data.
        setDisplayedSlot(hours.map(() => days.map(() => ""))); 

        const schedule = possibleSchedules[currentSchedule];

        // this function calls `setDisplayedSlots` to fill the correct data cells,
        // for given `schedule`
        updateTable(schedule);
    }, [currentSchedule]);
```

This didn't work as I expected, what happens is, the table isn't cleared and data from the previous schedule data remained if the corresponding cell isn't overridden by the newly selected schedule.

I thought this is due to the asynchronous nature of the react state updates. (?)

To work around this, I have added new state,

```js
const [isTableClear, setIsTableClear] = useState(false);
```

Changed the previous `useEffect` and added another one,

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setDisplayedSlot(hours.map(() => days.map(() => ""))); // clears table
        setIsTableClear(true);
    }, [currentSchedule]);

     useEffect(() => {
        if (isTableClear) {
            const schedule = possibleSchedules[currentSchedule];
            updateTable(schedule);
            setIsTableClear(false);
        }
    }, [isTableClear]);
```

This one works, but I have a feeling, this is a bit of a hack and not a react best practice at all. Since I am fairly new to react, I want to ask if this is a good solution, or how would you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you are queueing react state updates that depend on previous state then you should use a functional state update.

## Issue

You are enqueuing multiple state updates from within the same render cycle, each one using the state from the *current* render cycle, thus overwriting each previous state update.

## Solution

Since you enqueuing more than a single update to `displayedSlot` you need to do a functional update from the first state update. The first state update in the effect is ok since you are "wiping" state clean, subsequent updates should be functional.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setDisplayedSlot(hours.map(() => days.map(() => ""))); // <-- this is ok

    const schedule = possibleSchedules[currentSchedule];

    updateTable(schedule);
}, [currentSchedule]);
```

updateTable - Use a functional state update to take in any previous enqueued update to update from.

```
...

setDisplayedSlot(displayedSlot => {
  const updatedDisplayedSlot = displayedSlot.map(
    ...
    // logic to update specific slots
    ...
  );
  ...
  return updatedDisplayedSlot;
});

...
```

Comment: Thanks! This one solves it. Can I ask a quick question, can we omit the functional update every time on the first of the queued updates? In this case, it is the,  `setDisplayedSlot(hours.map(() => days.map(() => ""))); // <-- this is ok`.

Comment: @CagriUysal That is just a normal update. `hours.map(() => days.map(() => ""))` just resolves to a value.